# How to write a migration for a rails model that belongs_to itself

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

model scenario:

```
A node can belong to a parent node and can have child nodes.
```

models/node.rb

```
class Node < ActiveRecord::Base                                                                

  has_many :children, class_name: "Node", foreign_key: "parent_id"                             
  belongs_to :parent, class_name: "Node"                                                       

end
```

db/migrations/20131031144907_create_nodes.rb

```
class CreateNodes < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :nodes do |t|
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

And then I want to do I migration to add the relations:

```
class AddNodesToNodes < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :nodes, :parent_id, :integer
    # how do i add childen?
  end
end
```

**How do i add the has_many relationship in the migratation?**

Comment: As far as I can tell, you've done everything you needed to do. Are you getting some sort of error?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You've done everything you needed to do.You can find the more informations in this page:
[image]

Source: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

`node.parent` will find the `parent_id` is the node id and return the parent.

`node.children` will find the `parent_id` is the node id and return the children.

And when you add relations, you can do like this in Rails 4:

```
## rails g migration AddNodesToNodes parent:belongs_to

class AddNodesToNodes < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_reference :nodes, :parent, index: true
  end
end
```

Answer (score 13):

Per [RailsGuides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#self-joins), this is an example of a Self-Join.

```
# model
class Node < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :children, class_name: "Node", foreign_key: "parent_id"
  belongs_to :parent, class_name: "Node"
end

# migration
class CreateNodes < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :nodes do |t|
      t.references :parent, index: true
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no need for anything additional in the migration.  The parent_id is used to define the relationship in both directions.  Specifically:

1. parent - The Node with the id corresponding to the value of the parent_id attribute for the current Node.
2. children - All Nodes with a parent_id value corresponding to the value of the id attribute for the current Node.

Answer (score 1):

You've already written the migration with your AddNodeToNodes and the parent ID.

That defines it at the database level.

At the 'rails' level (ActiveRecord) you define the has_many in the **model** definition, i.e the Node.rb file that define the Node class.
There is no 'migration' to add has_many.  Migrations are used for database fields (and indexes, etc.) such a as `parent_id` but not for rails style relationship definitions such as `has_many`.